# jQuery UI Nested Sortable, sending additional data

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Another question relating to [jQuery UI Nested Sortable 1.2.1](http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable).

We call the function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('ol.sortable').nestedSortable({
disableNesting: 'no-nest',
forcePlaceholderSize: true,
handle: 'div',
items: 'li',
opacity: .6,
placeholder: 'placeholder',
tabSize: 25,
tolerance: 'pointer',
toleranceElement: '> div'
});
```

I was thinking how can I send additional information through this, like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('ol.sortable').nestedSortable({
disableNesting: 'no-nest',
forcePlaceholderSize: true,
handle: 'div',
items: 'li',
left_val: '<?=$lft?>',
root_id: '<?=$id?>', 
opacity: .6,
placeholder: 'placeholder',
tabSize: 25,
tolerance: 'pointer',
toleranceElement: '> div'
});
```

Idea is to use the three variables, left_val, root_id and holder in the following fashion in the toArray function.

```
var left = this.left_val;
var root_id = this.root_id;
```

This is not working, of course. Values are coming out as NaN, NaN and undefined.

Doing an `alert(left+' '+root_id);` just below `var left = this.left_val; var root_id = this.root_id;` is giving me an alert stating `undefined undefined`

The options of options are coming from the [parent plugin jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#options).

Just wondering if anyone can throw light to this, please.

**EDIT:**

I tried a different trick. I tried to send the left and root_id values through `<ol class="sortable" title="<?=$lft?>|<?=$id?>">` and then in the js page, I tried

```
if ($(this).parent().attr('class') == 'sortable') {
var idArray = $(this).parent().attr('title').split("|");
}
```

But I'm getting `$(this).parent().attr('class')` as `undefined` on alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is finally solved with:

```
var idArray =$(this.element).closest("ol.sortable").attr('title').split("|");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at JQuery.data() ? This will let you store arbitrary data in key/value pairs with a element. 
[JQuery Data() Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)

Here is some more documentation [Link](http://api.jquery.com/data)

Comment: Thanks Kyle. The data is highly interesting. However, data is apparently not a part of the available options, as per [this jquery UI page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#options).